# Preventing lazy edits

Tags: feature-request, edits

Is there any way we can prevent lazy edits done by all users?

I've come across several questions recently that had obvious edit-worthy body text like this:

> i am working on asp.net project(vs2005).. i having trouble wiht it this

It bothers me when I see that one or more high(ish) rep users have already edited the question and simply formatted code or added tags but ignored the spelling and grammar (or vice-versa).  I saw [this question's edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22351367/revisions) today and that was what led me to ask this question.  To me, this is the key issue, that users who should know better are just being lazy.

I feel like if you took the time to do some edits, and ignored/missed other potential places for edits that are obvious enough to systematically pick up on (more than one 'i', two periods), we should do something to alert the editing user like we do with not allowing titles like "plz help i have C# question".

I understand that's the point of the edit review queue, but that's only applicable to lower rep users (like myself).  Would it be so bad if we added a blip that said something like "it looks like there could be more to edit"? The user could decide between two buttons, like "just do my existing edits" and "I'll take another look".

I know UI changes are often frowned upon, but I was curious if anyone had any other ideas.

Comment: More minor edits are problematic for suggested edits due to the resources that they consume.  The vast majority of those problems go away for 2k+ rep users, so the negative consequences of making edits of the magnitude in your example just aren't really a problem, or if they are, certainly not a major one.

Comment: That looks like a pretty decent edit to me, although the editor missed some stuff.  Editing is a crowdsourcing activity... just finish what he started; he made less work for you.  The same cannot be said of suggested edits, which consume reviewers' time approving or rejecting them.

Comment: With automatic CW gone, and with the edit not going to the queue, I'd say that that edit is not only not a problem, but is welcome.

Comment: I am a high rep "lazy" user but the reason I rarely fix grammar and spelling is because English is not my primary language. Writing proper English without making spelling mistakes requires much more effort for me than fixing formatting and links.

Comment: not everyone is as bothered by minor typos as others are

Answer (score 77):

If an edit makes a post better but misses some other opportunities to make it better, it's still better than if they didn't edit the post at all.

I don't think that editors should be obligated to hunt for everything else that can possibly be edited. They're using their own personal time to try to make the post better, for free.  They're allowed to be lazy.

Comment: Specially if the edit in question is to fix some grammar/language mistake. I'm not fluent in English, and wouldn't feel embarrassed if someone correct my posts, but I'm sure a lot of people would. I think what really needs to be edited/reviewed is the code part of it, which is what really makes the question.

Comment: Now someone please correct the text in my comment. :)

Comment: @MelanciaUK, I'm English and can't see anything wrong with your comment :-) I was taught at school that you should never put a comma (,) before a joining word like `and` or `but`, but if it helps the sentence read then I'd say it's helpful!

Comment: @LukeCousins good tip! Thanks! :) 8 years living in the UK and I'm still learning new things everyday.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I think you only put a comment before your conjunctions if it's followed by another subject, so `"and wouldn't feel embarassed..."` doesn't need a comma, but `"but I'm sure a lot of people would"` does.

Comment: The commas in @MelanciaUK's comment are fine.  It's perfectly legitimate, and sometimes necessary, to put a comma before a conjunction.

Answer (score 16):

An editor's "job" is to make the post better. Not necessarily to find and fix everything that's wrong with a given post.

Still, many of us try to fix everything wrong *that we notice* once we start to edit a post, but **it's human nature to miss "obvious" *problem Y* when you are focused on *problem X*.**

Ask anyone who's ever edited a book.  You have to make lots of separate passes, focusing on different issues each time, and you are *still* amazed at the things you miss. (Even bestselling books with dozens of proofreaders have this problem.)

Looking at [the list of people who edited your "triggering" question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22351367/revisions), I'd hardly call them "lazy". One of the editors is a respected diamond moderator and he still missed some issues.

It takes many passes and/or many eyes to fix some of the posts we see.  Don't assume poor motives if somebody misses something; it can be a side effect of being focused.

Answer (score 2):

With less than 2k reputation, the edit gets sent to a review queue, where a few people need to look at it and see if it's okay. This needs to happen regardless of how much or little you change.

The question also gets sent to the front page, which obviously isn't going to make a big difference if the question is new or had recent activity.

So:

- If you have less than 2k reputation **OR**
- The question hasn't had recent activity

You should at least fix a few things in the post (assuming there are a few problems, otherwise it's a choice between a somewhat minor edit and leaving the problem there... forever?).

---

But trying to catch this automatically is likely going to be flawed. For example, checking number of characters changed could still leave massive problems in the post, and disallow good edits or force people to make silly changes to get around the limit when there isn't other problems or they're just feeling lazy.

The way to deal with this is to manually look at applicable edits, and possibly warn and eventually edit ban where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already answer this question pretty well, but if you're a **low-rep user** and can only suggest edits, then I would suggest **fixing as many issues as possible in the post when suggesting an edit** because all edits need to be reviewed by reviewers in the suggested edits queue.

Therefore, if you're being "lazy" and only fix some issues but leave some important ones in the post, you're really wasting the reviewers' time. (And your edit could be rejected as too minor!)

If you've got the edit privilege, then that's not a problem and all edits (even minor ones) are welcome<sup>*</sup>, as they do not need reviews.

---

<sup>* As long as the edit is constructive or useful.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is a crowd-sourced site, there were no obligations users subscribed for when they registered they accounts. Everyone improves as much as he thinks he has to. Some of the editors spend really much time on this page and *read "through" lines*, so may not even notice the obvious. Even if they do, and skip it, they just want to get to editing other questions/answers quicker.

For editors who's edits get reviewed, there is a special button in the review called `Improve`, which is made exactly for this (but not limitted to).