# Moderator overriding a user's approved tag-only edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

While reviewing suggested edits, I came across a few tag-only edits by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3367799/jjj). The majority of them added [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to questions tagged [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) that were missing the python tag. Most of them I found I either approved, improved, or skipped, and almost all of them ended up being approved.

However, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3367799/jjj?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), a moderator has rejected all of this user's recent edits (except for one that was overridden by the post owner and 4 that the moderator rejected before they were approved). I don't see anything really *wrong* with these edits. Yes, they were *minor* edits, but they still made substantial improvements for users who search for questions by tag.

Is there something I'm missing here? What is the reason for the rejection of these already-approved edits?

Comment: Before starting bulk edits (like "add phyton to all pandas questions") one is expected to have Meta discussion... I don't remember one on this topic...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov are you sure? I've never seen anything anywhere that said meta discussions are expected before bulk editing. Can you share the source that said that?

Comment: I don't think there is an official post of such kind (so posted as comment, "expected" is too strong word), but pretty much every time someone goes on  such editing spree there is meta discussion about it (like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295858/mass-editing-in-kbd-tags). Bulk edits push non-interesting content to active questions lists and thus impact a lot of people... And overall sentiment for bulk minor edits is "probably no" (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258424/serial-editing-in-general-acceptable-or-not/258459). So asking in advance would help.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, edits bump questions to the homepage. But in this case, these edits were worth it. No, they didn't fix every issue with every question, but that's why further edits are allowed. The post could continue being improved rather than the edits being rejected and the positive improvements not being kept.

Comment: "Should we add python to pandas questions" is very different question from you are asked in this post. You may as well ask it separately. (I don't know either of the tags well enough to suggest one way or another but this tag edits look minor to me)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay, I'm creating a different question for that subject.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322850/user-below-2k-reputation-burninating-tag-and-flooding-the-review-queue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The edits were flagged by another user as being too minor and not making other improvements to the posts.

I reviewed the edits and agreed. In addition most of the questions were several years old so the benefits of adding the python tag would be marginal at best.

While the posts may well have been missing the python tag, and some of the posts might not have required any other edits, there was no attempt to make more general improvements to any of the posts.

If they'd made more extensive edits to at least some of the questions I probably would have left them alone.

Don't forget that by suggesting edits you're making work for other people who have to review those edits. By making minor edits to posts you're making work for little gain. Once you've got 2,000 reputation points you can make minor edits to your heart's content.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your reasoning. However, I completely disagree with it. Searching for python questions is *considerably* easier when you just type in "[python]" rather than having to make separate searches for [python], [pandas], [python-3.x], etc, which is what has to happen when questions tagged [pandas] don't have a more general language tag as well, which in this case is [python].

Comment: @JJJ the question you link to is talking about edits from users above 2K rep. When edits don't need to be reviewed, it is easier to make a case for incomplete edits.

Comment: @JJJ the author is also not the person who did the edits he is disputing.... That's the question discussed in that other post. Everyone on it is over 2K, except the OP : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22351367/revisions

Comment: +, on the very post you link, one of the answers explains exactly what is happening here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256854/2417948. You may have done a bit of barnshooter effect in your research :/

Comment: @JJJ maybe, but then the right move may be to wait for you to have 2K rep and get your edits through? I mean, I am just telling you the consensus, which is 'fix everything if you are to edit a post'. Since it takes reviewer time, it's not a bad idea (And btw,  at least local to me, confirmation bias is often talked about as 'barnshooter effect'. There was no ill intent or pun intended. The CoC does talk about assuming people don't have Ill intent. Plz don't jump to conclusions too quickly and start throwing 'offense' around.)

Comment: @Patrice you may want to be a bit more careful using local terms - https://www.bing.com/search?q=barnshooter find some meanings that may not be [the best](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Barnshoot) ). Never heard of that phrase used so...

Comment: @Alexei fair enough. Lesson learned. You do learn something new everyday. Wow. Completely different than the 'confirmation bias' meaning I had intended.

Comment: For what it's worth, words have different meanings in different places. Before claiming offense or insensitivity, try to remember that while X means X to you, sometimes to somebody else around the world it means Y.