# Should questions tagged [pandas] also be tagged [python]?

Tags: discussion, tags, code-languages

There was some disagreement in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381191) about whether questions tagged [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) should also be tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), so I'm asking this question so as to avoid future disagreements about this.

Often, I come across questions with the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) tag but not the tag for the programming language, which in this case is [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). I also sometimes find suggested edits adding [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to these questions, and I want to make sure I review these right.

So, should [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) questions also be tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or not?

Comment: I'd like to note that this is not "feature-request" - indeed everyone is free to vote any way they want but please consider voting on answers if you for/against this rather than "this is badly written post because I disagree with this feature request".

Comment: I don't know panda/python but your question sound to me like "should we tag [jquery] question with [Javascript]?" and the answer is no .. jQuery is a JS library/framework but the question might concern only the use of jQuery or a bug/issue related to jQuery

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't know jQuery very well, but it sounds like questions about it don't necessarily have to be closely related to JavaScript. It's not like that with pandas/python: pandas programs are written in python. Period. If it's related to pandas, it's also related to python.

Comment: Thanks for noting that, @AlexeiLevenkov. This isn't a feature request, but it's the type of discussion that should be voted on based on opinion.

Comment: a jQuery program is also written in JS

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I am of the opinion that **yes, [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) questions should also be tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)**. Here's why:

- It makes searching easier by only requiring you to search once to find python questions rather than twice (it would also require searching for questions tagged [pandas] if we don't include [python] on pandas questions).
- There are [85400 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas+python) with both [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) compared to [12631](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas+-python) questions tagged [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and not [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).
- It just makes sense - both [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) are closely related to the question, and thus should both be included in the question's tags.

A similar discussion was [brought up on Arqade.Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12017/do-you-need-the-minecraft-tag-for-minecraft-commands-or-minecraft-redstone), and the general consensus was that it made tag watching and ignoring easier. It also makes a lot of other things, most of which I've already mentioned.