# Do we need a pandas-1, pandas-1.0, or pandas-1.x tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The release of Pandas 1.0 is imminent.  The first release candidate [was released 2020-01-10](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pandas-dev/2020-January/001173.html).  This release introduces [major changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html), including backward compatibility changes, compared to Pandas 0.x.  I just asked (I believe) [the first Pandas 1.0 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59856138/974555), but considering the major changes I think we can expect many in the future.

Two questions on tagging:

- Do we need a tag for the new pandas version?
- If yes, how should it be spelled?  Some suggestions include [pandas-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-1.0), [pandas-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-1), or [pandas-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-1.x).  I've tagged my Pandas 1.0 question [pandas-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-1.0), but perhaps [pandas-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-1.x) is more future-proof.

Comment: Are there any questions about 1.0 already?

Comment: @BDL I [just asked the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59856138/974555) :)

Comment: Is it foreseeable that [tag:pandas-1.1] will require its own tag too because the developers are already planning breaking changes for it? That would inform the decision for the best tag format.

Comment: @deceze No, breaking changes should only occur between major versions (semantic versioning).  On the other hand, we do have [tag:python-3.7], [tag:python-3.8], etc., although those exist in addition to [tag:python-3.x].

Comment: Yes, so the same scheme is probably warranted, [tag:pandas-1.x] in addition to [tag:pandas-1.0].

Comment: Perhaps, but then there's a problem if pandas questions are tagged *[tag:python] [tag:pandas] [tag:pandas-1.x]* as per [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381193/should-questions-tagged-pandas-also-be-tagged-python), that only allows two other tags.

Comment: And to be clear, is [tag:pandas-1.x] only intended for breaking/new changes/deprecation in pandas 1.x wrt 0.x, or going forward for all pandas-related questions? (in which case it duplicates [tag:pandas], which would be bad idea).