# Do we need a [pandas-2.x] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

I know there is no [pandas-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-1.x) [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393206/15239951).

However, a new major version of Pandas (2.0.0) was released on April 3, 2023. Obviously, there are some deep changes (and many bugs). The first questions about this specifically version are starting to arrive.

I wonder if this isn't a good opportunity to create [pandas-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-2.x) tag (and why not [pandas-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-1.x) (synonym of [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)?)) like it is for [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (or [ansible-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-1.x) and [ansible-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-2.x)).

Some relevant questions:

- [DataFrame object has no attribute append](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75956209/15239951)
- [Is there a work around for Pandas 2.0 deprecation of pyodbc for obscure databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75943293/15239951)
- [Very slow aggregate on Pandas 2.0 dataframe with pyarrow as dtype_backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75917750/15239951)
- [Editing a Column of a DataFrame in Pandas Version 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75805967/15239951)
- [Anyone know how to display a pandas dataframe in Databricks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75922697/15239951)
- [Pandas read_sql_query with SQLAlchemy 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75258045/15239951)

[pandas-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-2.x): DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PANDAS 2 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [pandas] tag.

Comment: The Python tags are quite a mess. Do we really benefit from repeating that pattern?

Comment: Version tags seem to lure people into using them instead of the unversioned tag. Better off without them. People can still specify what version they're using without needing a tag for it.

Comment: There was actually a "pandas-1.0" tag which had a handful of questions (13) which I've now merged into the main pandas tag. Given the conversation and resolution here, I did also make [tag:pandas-1.x] and [tag:pandas-2.x] synonyms of [tag:pandas] which will prevent users from creating these tags (since they already exist) and keep all questions under the pandas umbrella. If for whatever reason the synonyms need to be removed that can easily be done by a moderator at any point in the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not really in favor of it.

Version specific tags are not always used wisely. Askers most often don't provide the library version, what is the chance that they would use a correct version tag?

We already have to constantly request for reproducible examples and clarifications. I have the feeling that a new tag would be more a burden than a useful tool.

If something should be done I would rather be in favor of encouraging to systematically provide the library version in the question. Maybe as a temporary highlight in the [pandas tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info). Or as a banner/tooltip when the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) tag is added in the "Ask a question" form [like for the sql/regex tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql).

Something along the lines of:

> A new major pandas version is out (pandas 2.0, see [what's new](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html)), with a significant number of [deprecations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#deprecations) and [backwards incompatible API changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-api-changes).
>
> Please make sure to provide your exact `pandas` version for clarity and reproducibility. This can be obtained by running `print(pd.__version__)`

Also relevant, [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365015/usefulness-of-the-python-3-x-tag) on the usefulness of the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag.

Answer (score 3):

### Creating [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) was a mistake in the first place

It caused a huge assortment of problems:

- Tons of questions are tagged with both, **even for things where the version doesn't actually matter**
- There are tons of questions where the code might need small changes to work in one version or the other (and probably even some where there just isn't a way to write the code that's compatible with both) but the **answer to the question is the same**
- Tons of questions tagged with one or the other (or both) are **not tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)**, which interferes with curation
- Each such tag **counts against a very strict limit** (5), reducing the room to describe other important facets of the question
- It **doesn't stand the test of time**: nowadays there's no good reason to treat 3.x specially (since all 2.x branches have been completely unsupported for more than 3 years), but people still do it sometimes, and there is no process or initiative to retag old questions en masse

### The approach doesn't scale

There are **relatively few issues that are actually specific** to minor versions, but a huge array of extra tags, which compounds all of the above problems. The minor-version tags are unpopular (the biggest is [python-3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.6) at about 5.6k questions - i.e., about one days' worth of questions for the site), and **when they do get used they're rarely useful**.

Even for the 3.6 tag, I would consider a gold tag badge to be quite the feat. I certainly don't have one - despite my reputation as a subject matter expert, active curator and active Meta contributor, I only this year got a *silver* [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) badge! (Incidentally, 3.6 is also EOL, and 3.7 will be EOL this year.)

A major problem here is that tags get applied primarily by OP, who knows what version of Python was used to run the code, but **likely doesn't know whether or how that's relevant**. There's a culture of volunteering such information that comes from support forums, because people get used to being asked for that kind of information when they *don't* supply it. However, when it turns out not to be relevant to causing the problem, in a Stack Overflow question it's just noise. Having extra tags encourages more noise.

Aside from that - consider features that are added in a minor version, like f-strings in 3.6. Suppose someone comes along using an older version, and asks why f-strings don't work (we do have a canonical for that, I'm pretty sure...). **What version should you tag for that?** 3.6, because it's the version associated with the feature? 3.5, because it's the last version where the *problem* occurs? Or else the version that OP was using, *even though it isn't specific* to that minor version?

And then there's the problem of questions about updating the code for new versions, etc. There are tons of old questions about changes in behaviour between 2.x and 3.x, or about how to fix code written for 2.x so that it works in 3.x. Putting both tags on those seems not very useful (plus they also need the base [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag in order for most curators to be able to do their jobs properly, and then you only have *two* remaining tag slots). There's also a [python2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2to3) which is *supposed to be* specifically about a standard library tool for doing such migration, but the already very small pool of questions got polluted with general migration questions. And, again, **nobody is exactly volunteering to clean up that mess**. I tried to put a dent in it once. I think I'd rather chew tinfoil.

### Pandas 1 and 2 are unlikely to be as different anyway

Going from Python 2.x to 3.x was a *huge* issue for *many* people and a lot of *very big and important* organizations, adding up to an *unfathomably large* pile of code. Plus the initial versions of 3.x were a) not great (in my book it was practically unusable until 3.2) and b) released at a time when many people were still set in their old ways ("why should I have to care about text encoding? and treat strings and byte-sequences as separate types? My local code page works just fine for MY platform!"). The last 2.x release 2.7, was given *double* the normal support duration (i.e. *ten years*).

<sub>Yet people *still* complain about how it's somehow everyone else's fault that they're now over three years behind schedule on migration, chasing a target that might also be 6 minor versions old and also EOL, and struggling to suck it up and deal with the fact that languages that use more than 256 glyphs exist.</sub>

I don't think "Y2K-esque" is an unreasonable adjective to apply to how the scenario played out.

**I would be surprised if Pandas 2 turned out to be more than a ripple in the ocean compared to that**. From what I've seen so far, the worst problems have been with people finding that their pickled Dataframes aren't loadable any more.

<sub>Really, the way Pickle works, *nobody* should expect *anything* pickled to survive *any* change to the installed libraries, or really anything else about the environment: it's meant to preserve *the exact structure of objects as they were created by the code, along with all their metadata like class names*. It's meant for *exact persistence, not* serialization on a semantic level. Please just use CSV, or JSON, or whatever else is appropriate to the kind of data you have.</sub>

<sub>Can you tell I'm not a big fan of being overly accommodating when it comes to backwards compatibility, by the way?</sub>